# Nodejs - npm install permanently freezes

Tags: node.js, npm, installation, freeze

## I am having weird issues with npm: the installation process permanently freezes on the load stage.

After nodejs installation, I tried to install angular-cli , but it stuck on the load stage:

```
c:\>npm install -g @angular/cli
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.10.10
npm info using node@v6.11.3
npm info ok
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.10.10
npm info using node@v6.11.3
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 1:35:34 PM
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli
npm info addNameTag [ '@angular/cli', 'latest' ]
[|||||..............] - loadRequestedDeps: info addNameTag [ '@angular/cli', 'latest' ]
```

Same thing happens with other packages installation, for example Yarn:

```
c:\>npm install -g yarn
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.10.10
npm info using node@v6.11.3
npm info ok
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@3.10.10
npm info using node@v6.11.3
npm info attempt registry request try #1 at 1:38:08 PM
npm http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/yarn
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/yarn
npm info addNameTag [ 'yarn', 'latest' ]
[|||||..............] \ loadRequestedDeps: info addNameTag [ 'yarn', 'latest' ]
```

Please help, what could be a possible reason for that and how to fix it ?

Comment: try running `npm cache clean` and then your install command

Comment: Already tried that - did not help.

Comment: also experiencing a freeze during npm install  


 npm install -verbose
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm verb cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'install', '-verbose' ]
npm info using npm@6.4.1
npm info using node@v10.12.0
npm verb npm-session acf2a85833fe29b2
npm info lifecycle PeerJavascriptChat@1.0.0~preinstall: PeerJavascriptChat@1.0.0   
npm timing stage:loadCurrentTree Completed in 9ms   
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:cloneCurrentTree Completed in 0ms  
npm timing stage:loadIdealTree:loadShrinkwrap Completed in 1ms

Comment: click  and enter over terminal console and wait some seconds

Answer (score 0):

For me adding additional memory to a system helped.

I was running npm install on a linux vm with only 1GB RAM. Adding swap file with a size of 4GB totally helped.

I hope this helps someone)